# pandas apply function to row: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a df, code is here:

```
df4s = """
    contract  RB  BeginDate  ValIssueDate   EndDate   Valindex0
2  A00118  46   19850100      19880901  99999999          50
3  A00118  47   19000100      19880901  19831231          47
5  A00118  47   19850100      19880901  99999999          50
6  A00253  48   19000100      19820101  19811231          47
7  A00253  48   19820100      19820101  19841299          47
8  A00253  48   19850100      19820101  99999999          50
9  A00253  50   19000100      19820101  19781231          47
10 A00253  50   19790100      19820101  19841299          47
11 A00253  50   19850100      19820101  99999999          50

"""
df4 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df4s.strip()), sep='\s+', 
                  dtype={"RB": str, "BeginDate": int, "EndDate": int,'ValIssueDate':int,'Valindex0':int})
```

output:

```
contract    RB  BeginDate   ValIssueDate    EndDate Valindex0
2   A00118  46  19850100    19880901    99999999    50
3   A00118  47  19000100    19880901    19831231    47
5   A00118  47  19850100    19880901    99999999    50
6   A00253  48  19000100    19820101    19811231    47
7   A00253  48  19820100    19820101    19841299    47
8   A00253  48  19850100    19820101    99999999    50
9   A00253  50  19000100    19820101    19781231    47
10  A00253  50  19790100    19820101    19841299    47
11  A00253  50  19850100    19820101    99999999    50
```

And I want to add a new column :

```
df4['n']
```

base on one of an existed column df4['RB'] like this:

```
def test(RB):
    n=1
    for i in range(RB,50):
        n+=1
    return n

df4['n']=test(df4['RB'].values)
```

But I receive an error by using this numpy way:

```
<ipython-input-18-3831e3b8068d> in test(RB)
     17 def test(RB):
     18     n=1
---> 19     for i in range(RB,50):
     20         n+=1
     21     return n

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Because If I print the RB inside the test function the value is not a single value it is an array :

```
['46' '47' '47' '48' '48' '48' '50' '50' '50']
```

But if I use a slower method it works:

```
def test(row):
    n=1
    for i in range(int(row['RB']),50):
        n+=1

df4['n'] = df4.apply(lambda row: test(row), axis=1)
```

The right output is:

```
contract    RB  BeginDate   ValIssueDate    EndDate Valindex0   n
2   A00118  46  19850100    19880901    99999999    50          5
3   A00118  47  19000100    19880901    19831231    47          4
5   A00118  47  19850100    19880901    99999999    50          4
6   A00253  48  19000100    19820101    19811231    47          3
7   A00253  48  19820100    19820101    19841299    47          3
8   A00253  48  19850100    19820101    99999999    50          3
9   A00253  50  19000100    19820101    19781231    47          1
10  A00253  50  19790100    19820101    19841299    47          1
11  A00253  50  19850100    19820101    99999999    50          1
```

I want to use the faster way,to do this,not slower way,is any way I can fix the first method?The goal is using loop in method 1.

This is just a sample example,my exact function is very complicated ,it looks like:

```
def getnpx(df, age, interest):
    val = 1
    initval = 1
    print(age.astype(int))
    for i in np.arange(age.astype(int), 136):
        val = val * df[str(i)].values
        intval = val / (1 + interest) ** (i + 1 - age)
        initval = initval + intval
    return initval
```

Comment: `df4['RB'].values` passed to your function as `RB` is an array (1d).  It cannot be used in the python range function.  The `range` arguments have to be single numbers (re-read your basic python).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply ,so what need I do ,can you give more detail answer?

Comment: Usually you can't just write a function that works with scalars, and expect it to work when given many numbers (whether in a list, array, or Series).  You can call it once for each number as you do with `apply`.  I believe `apply` haa a `raw` mode that might improve speed (see its docs).  But to take full advantage of `numpy` arrays, you have to  take some time to actually learn `numpy`.

Comment: You are confusing the issues, you have test data and a real function that don't match.  Please provide the real function with some explanation, test data to match, and expected output from the real function and this test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the way how to do that:

```
vfunc=np.vectorize(test)
df4['n']=vfunc(df4['RB'].values)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you attempt to do in a complex way is simply a subtraction.

Try instead:

```
df['n'] = 51 - df['RB'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, please check my update,I think this is not the right way to do it,if it is very complicated.

Comment: for example what I need to do is very complicated logic like the end of this question I have posted ,not such a easy logic.

Comment: I unfortunately can't have a detailed look now, but you should try to make your operation vectorial. Do you really need a loop? Write down the formula and see if it can be simplified.

Comment: What you do is **not** complicated, it looks like a series. There are formulas to access a given value without calculating all three intermediates.

Comment: yes, really ,thank you so much ,can you give more detail answer ?

Comment: Unfortunately not now, I'll try tomorrow

Comment: Thank you very much!